# how to change ArrayBuffer of a TypedArray?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arraybuffer

I have an ArrayBuffer and use it for making some typedArray(each one of them pointing to 4 element on buffer) something [like a C struct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)
but I need to change this buffer size to change count of this TypedArrays, is there any way to change buffer of exists arrays? I want to keep access on these values from out(objects which has known this arrays )

thanks in advance

Comment: No, [apparently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/buffer) you cannot change it

Comment: Bergi is right. You cannot change it but you must replace it with another buffer.

Comment: isn't any other way to not making a new Arraybuffer for previous data? (for reading them from out via having the previous ArrayBuffer)